# static functions in multiple files

Tags: c, function, static

I am trying to break up a c program into two different files. I am using static functions and i am wondering how that is going to affect my transition to two files. I want all my functions in one file and all the call in the other. What do I need to do to use static functions is two different files?

Comment: Have you considered not using static functions?

Comment: Static functions have "internal linkage" -- they stay put in the file they're declared in. You can just define the same static functions in multiple files but a better solution depends on the details of your problem.

Comment: What noone seems to have mentioned is that there is no problem whatsoever in #including a C file into another C file. I do it to keep functions static in particular circumstances while keeping file sizes manageable. (If you don't like that, well, that's a religious argument not a programming one.)

Answer (score 1):

static means invisible to other files. Please learn the basics.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing

Comment: There is a big difference between static functions in C and static member functions in C++. In C, a static function is not visible outside of its translation unit, which is the object file it is compiled into. In other words, making a function static limits its scope. You can think of a static function as being "private" to its *.c file (although that is not strictly correct).

Comment: In C++, "static" applies to member functions and data members of classes. A static data member is also called a "class variable", while a non-static data member is an "instance variable". This is Smalltalk terminology. This means that there is only one copy of a static data member shared by all objects of a class, while each object has its own copy of a non-static data member. So a static data member is essentially a global variable, that is a member of a class.

Comment: Non-static member functions can access all data members of the class: static and non-static. Static member functions can only operate on the static data members.

Comment: Better, but not enough. Listing book data about "static" won't solve your problem. In both C and C++, the static keyword applied to a function results in a function with internal linkage. It's the C way to implement encapsulation. So calling a function static and requesting to call it from another translation unit is a paradox. In the worst case you need at least 1 entry point which is not static, but in general, none of the functions should be static.

Answer (score 0):

the linkage of static function in C is only within one file, so you can call static function which is in different source files.
So you may need to this

in a.c

```
int bar(){return 1;}
```

int b.c which is going to call bar function

```
int bar(); /*declaration the function type*/
void foo(){bar();} /* just call it*/
```

Answer (score 0):

the most robust solution is to first declare the 'globally visible' function in a header file and then include this header file in all functions that define or reference the function.

---

app.h:

```
#ifndef _APP_H    //why this? left as an excercise for the reader ;-)
#define _APP_H
...
//declare fun()
extern   int   fun(char * strArg);
...
#endif
```

---

def.c:

```
#include "app.h"
//define fun()
int   fun(char * strArg)
{
   ....
}
```

---

ref.c:

```
#include "app.h"
....
//reference fun()
int ret = fun("this is a test");
....
```

==========

this way you make sure that all references to fun() are invoking it correctly.
and if you happen to change fun() in any way, or invoke it incorrectly,
the compiler will tell you where all the changes/fixes need to be done.

in any case, if you want anything to be visible outside of a specific source file it better not have a 'static' attribute.
because the purpose of the static attribute is to make whatever is static invisible outside of the source file.

========